# Query Importrange with multiple values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

[image]

This formula is working fine, but I need to add in other teams into Column A. I would need to return ATT SLC, ATT Orem, and ATT Scottsdale within this same range, but I'm not sure the language to use to extend the return values

Hopefully the image is readable, if not here is the query I'm working on

```
=query(importrange("Google Doc URL","Total Summary!A:K"),"where Col1='ATT SLC'")
```

Again I think it would go something like this, ("Where Col1='ATT SLC','ATT Orem' etc) to get more than one team on a single import.

Answer (score 1):

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("key/url", "Total Summary!A:K"), "where Col1='ATT SLC' 
                                                        or Col1='ATT Orem' 
                                                        or Col1='ATT Scottsdale'")
```